# SQL Activity Primary Key Violation

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

This is the error i get:

> Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'WEALTH_BOUNCE'. The duplicate key value is (00328000011d2qXAAQ, Pengana_Client_IOOF, 20201030, 23175718, MPMPPT)."

Query:

```sql
SELECT distinct
    BS.Recipient_ID,
    BS.EmailAddress,
    BS.Campaign_ID,
    BS.Sub_Campaign_ID,
    BS.Email_ID,
    BS.JobID,
    BS.Badge,
    B.BounceCategory [Bounce Type],
    B.BounceSubcategory [Bounce Reason],
    B.SMTPBounceReason [Bounce Description],
    DateAdd(hh,17,B.EventDate) [Bounce Date],
    B.Domain [Bounce Domain] 
FROM
    WEALTH_BOUNCE_SENDS BS WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
    [_Bounce] B WITH (NOLOCK) ON BS.Recipient_ID = B.SubscriberKey AND BS.JobID = B.JobID
```

The target DE has 0 records.

Primary Key fields in target DE:

- Recipient_ID
- Campaign_ID
- Sub_Campaign_ID
- JobID
- Badge

What should be the problem?

Comment: It appears you have a PK issue. I always recommend you remove your PK and review your data ( or copy your target DE and remove your PK fields). Most likely due to your join

Comment: Removing PK is not possible for some business needs we want them.

Comment: that's why I recommend making a copy of the target de and reviewing the data. You have duplicate records on your PK and the query is erroring

Comment: Please update your question and list the 5 primary key fields in your target data extension.

Comment: This is one of the worst tries to make data anonymous ;) First you used a transparent color to hide the e-mail adress and second the email address is visible on bounce description ;) Please fix it if you don't want to expose this information

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JohannesSchapdick ;-) am new to this space!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a `select distinct` will not prevent a primary key violation.  You'll need to either **(1)** relax your primary key (as [@EasyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) suggested), or **(2)** use a windowing function to rank and pick one of the duplicate rows.

**Option 1**

Relaxing the target data extension's primary key is a good approach if you aren't sure what constitutes uniqueness in the data sets you're joining together.

**Option 2**

If you do understand the keys and relationships, you can use a windowing function to pick one of the rows. It's a little abstract, but very flexible.

Assuming your target data extension's primary key is `Recipient_ID + Campaign_ID + Sub_Campaign_ID + JobID + Badge`, this query would only return the most recent bounce event row for each combination of the primary key fields -- as specified in the `partition by` clause:

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
  BS.Recipient_ID
, BS.EmailAddress
, BS.Campaign_ID
, BS.Sub_Campaign_ID
, BS.Email_ID
, BS.JobID
, BS.Badge
, B.BounceCategory [Bounce Type]
, B.BounceSubcategory [Bounce Reason]
, B.SMTPBounceReason [Bounce Description]
, DateAdd(hh,17,B.EventDate) [Bounce Date]
, B.Domain [Bounce Domain] 
FROM WEALTH_BOUNCE_SENDS BS 
INNER JOIN [_Bounce] B ON BS.Recipient_ID = B.SubscriberKey AND BS.JobID = B.JobID
order by row_number() over (
    partition by 
      BS.Recipient_ID
    , BS.Campaign_ID
    , BS.Sub_Campaign_ID
    , BS.JobID
    , BS.Badge 
    order by b.eventDate desc 
)
```

My rule of thumb for addressing PK violations -- "just partition by the target data extension's primary key fields and pick one by the order-by".

I have a long-form example of the partition [**here on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/picking-rows-with-partitions/).

Comment: Hi Adam- In option 2 what if the WEALTH_BOUNCE_SENDS DE has dupes?

Comment: You are right the dupes come from _Bounce DV, but how can I get the values for  B.BounceCategory [Bounce Type]
, B.BounceSubcategory [Bounce Reason]
, B.SMTPBounceReason [Bounce Description]
, DateAdd(hh,17,B.EventDate) [Bounce Date]
, B.Domain [Bounce Domain] Since they are not used in Aggregate function in Group.

Comment: I've removed that sub-query JOIN example from my answer.  It just overcomplicates the solution.  I typically use a windowing function to handle this. It doesn't matter if WEALTH_BOUNCE_SENDS has duplicates, you can include that DEs value in your partition if needed.

Comment: Thanks Adams...

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark on the left.  It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help to get your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).